# USB keyboards keep disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, usb, keyboard

Issue: USB keyboard keeps disconnecting and reconnecting. It has disconnected 6 times as I've typed this post. It generally reconnects after about 3 seconds.

- OS: Win 7 Pro 64 bit
- MB: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.  Z87M-D3H
- RAM: 8 gigs

(Anything else I can supply if needed.)

I have tried literally everything I can think of.
I've Googled this question to death.
Things I have tried:

- Unplugging and plugging it back in
- Plugging it into a different USB port
- Plugging it into a USB 2.0 port
- Plugging it into a USB 3.0 port
- Going to Device Manager -> USB -> unchecking the box that says "Allow Windows to turn this device off to save power"
- Uninstalling and reinstalling drivers
- Making sure drivers are up to date
- Uninstalling all drivers except the manufacturer's driver
- Installing a different OS (tried installing Win 7 Pro from Win 7 Home, tried running an Ubuntu Live CD)
- Unplugging all other USB devices
- Trying a different USB keyboard
- Building a **whole new box** (every piece of hardware, barring monitor, mouse and keyboard, are new)

Interesting facts

- Keyboard does not disconnect if I plug it into my two year old laptop, while it does if I plug it into my brand new (purchased 2 days ago) machine. (Note: That machine is running Ubuntu. I don't think that should matter though, because Ubuntu was the other OS I tried to install on this machine.)
- However, I had the **exact same** issue with a box that I just replaced.
- Keyboard stays backlit when disconnected, but input is impossible. It still makes the Windows "You just unplugged a USB device" noise.

I am ready and willing to supply any and all information you think might help you debug this. I cannot try a PS2 keyboard because I do not have a PS2 keyboard on hand. Believe me, I would love to try a PS2 keyboard.

EDIT:
Sorry, tried to clarify with this edit. I did install an entirely new version of Windows (went from Home to Pro) but only tried running Ubuntu from an live CD. All hardware (except mouse, keyboard, and monitor) are new.

Comment: When you say "built a whole new box", was it all completely different parts (that is, did you reuse, say, the motherboard?). Does the problem occur when running from a Linux Live distro (wasn't quite clear what "installing a different OS" means)?

Comment: You could try your current keyboard in the ps2 port using an adapter. Most mice and hey boards I've purchased recently come with one. This would help rule out your keyboard. Have you checked the bios for any settings that may have an impact